# Hosted Credit Card Options for Admin and Frontend

Tags: payment-gateway

I'm searching for a hosted 3rd party credit card entry form (iframe) that works on both the admin order management screen and the frontend checkout. Something similar to how the payment bridge works in Enterprise Edition.

I reviewed the hosted page options "Paypal Payflow Link" and "PayPal Advanced Payments", but they only work on the frontend checkout.

Is there a hosted PCI Compliant credit card entry form that works in both areas? Or are there full service companies that host the Enterprise Payment Bridge that a merchant can connect to for processing?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/the-official-ingenico-former-ogone-extension.html which can handle credit card payments for front- and backend.

Comment: Thanks I think that is similar to what i'm look for. Do you know if that plugin can be used with Paypal as a credit card processor or is it the type that only works with certain processors?

Comment: You can use Paypal as separate payment method. But this method works for frontend only. Backend payments are bound to a so called alias which is supported by some credit card types (e.g. Visa).